# c++ exceptions throw by value catch by reference

Tags: c++, exception

In C++ when throwing object by value like: throw Exception(), this will create temp object, how can it be caught by reference? i know it works, but if it was a function return value or function call it would have failed without adding const to type, what is the difference ?

Comment: exceptions are different beasts, they have their own semantics.

Comment: it's a long topic... 3 hours of explanation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7fIy_54y-w IIRC, Scott Meyers' book also has some chapters on the topic...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, when you write

```
throw Exception();
```

what's being thrown isn't actually the temporary object created by the prvalue expression `Exception()`. Conceptually, there's a separate object - the exception object - that's initialized from that temporary object, and it is the exception object that's actually thrown. (Compilers are allowed to elide the copy/move, though.)

Second, the language rules say that the exception object is always considered an lvalue. Hence it is allowed to bind to non-const lvalue references.